# An original series from zeta function.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's have the following relation $\sum\limits_{1}^k (2m_1-1)(2m_2-1)\cdots(2m_k-1)2^{k-1}/k!$ where $m$ takes all values from 1 to $k$. When $k$ is odd we put a positive sign in front of the obtained integer and when $k$ is even a negative sign.

Does anyone know to express this series in a closed form? Up to $k=11$ we have the following 
$$\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{35}+\frac{1}
{126}-\frac{1}{462}+\frac{1}{1716}-\frac{1}{6435}+\frac{1}{24310}-\frac{1}{92378} +\frac{1}{352716} =0.744327739.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica can do it: The sum is

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\binom{2n+1}{n+1}} = \frac{2}{25}(5 + 4\sqrt{5}\,\operatorname{csch}^{-1}(2)).$$

[Wolfram alpha computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28-1%29%5En/Binomial%5B2n%20%2b%201,%20n%20%2b%201%5D%20where%20n%20from%200%20to%20infinity)